# Nsis ExecWait command under the hood

Tags: nsis

There's a nsis exe that I know it using Nsis ExecWait to run a process.I need to hook it so I could replace the exe it Exec.

The problem is I'm not sure about what api to hook.And I've try dive into Nsis source codes till now find nothing:(. So Is there anyone familiar with nsis source codes give me some clue so I could find what ExecWait command under the hood API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecWait` is currently just [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)+`WaitForSingleObject`.

In the NSIS source this instruction is called TOK_EXECWAIT in the compiler (script.cpp) and it maps to the EW_EXECUTE opcode in the installer stub (exehead/exec.c)...

Comment: Thanks 4 your Infos，I asked this for Hook,But After I did a R3 hook CreateProcessA/W,It made no effected,That's kind of weird，And After this I decided to choose another solution. Maybe In the future I'll take a debugger to find out what happened :)